# No map tiles loading when using Mapbox legacy when compiling with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, mapbox

I'm currently in charge of maintaining a legacy application, written in Xamarin (without .Forms, I code individual UIs per platform).

The code uses a rather very old version of Mapbox iOS [Mapbox iOS SDK Legacy](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy).

My problem is, **the map remains white**, even though all our custom map pins are all loaded without a hitch. It's **as if the tiles are not loaded**.

I have **compiled old versions** of the app that were released successfully, but the **problem persists**.

The only difference between my current setup and the guy who coded it before me is, that **I'm using a newer XCode version (Version 7)**.

Due to time constraints and existing code, refactoring the whole solution to use a more modern Mapbox implementation would only be my very last resort.

Does anybody have an idea what may be wrong, or what I could do? (Also non-Xamarin suggestions are more than welcome)

Thanks in advance, 
Cheers

Comment: A lot of things changed (and got broken) on xcode 7, if you don't want to rewrite your app maybe you can downgrade xcode and xamarin to be the same versions the previous programer used.

Comment: I feared as much, in that case maybe a refactoring is a good thing to happen. Thank you @Gusman

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution was in the URL the base tiles were fetched from.

Apparently the component fails quietly on iOS 9.2 when trying to load tiles from an **http** source.

I **changed the url to https** and now it works like a charm.